# iTunesConnect - TC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed build upload fail

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new build for my iOS app. The upload works fine through iTunes Connect. At first its status is "Processing" (just as normal). But suddenly I get the red alert and the following error message:
TC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed

I tried to upload another time but I got the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: same probleme here